# Reading image in React app component

Tags: jss, react

I have created one sample app in disconnected mode. Inside that, I have created 1 image component.
It works fine in disconnected mode but when I deploy it, to my sitecore instance then it will give an error with the following:

> "image issue in sitecore jss Minified React error #62; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=62&args[]= for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings."

Can anyone help me into this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think we need more details. Could extend the question with code of your image component? Also it would be helpful if you add the route where you added the component to the page

Comment: The Image Component has following code snippet: 
Index.js-->
const HomeBanner = (props) => (
  <div>
      <Image media={props.fields.bannerimage} />
     
  </div>
);

export default HomeBanner;
export default function(manifest) {
  manifest.addComponent({
    name: 'HomeBanner',
    icon: SitecoreIcon.DocumentTag,
    fields: [
      { name: 'bannerimagesrc', type: CommonFieldTypes.Image},
    ],
    inherits: ['styleguide-explanatory-component-template'],
  });
}